# Is this the same Magearna (the Mechanical Pokémon)?

Tags: pokemon

Is the Magearna from [*Pokémon Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon*](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Ultra_Sun_and_Ultra_Moon) (that Lillie gets passed down to her by her father) the same Magearna that was was built in the kingdom of Azoth, from [*Pokémon the Movie: Volcanion and the Mechanical Marvel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_the_Movie:_Volcanion_and_the_Mechanical_Marvel)?

Comment: The game isn't based in the same canon universe, but probably yes. In both continuities, Magearna is a unique built thing. There's no good indication that there's more than one of them and they presumably have the same backstory